# Computing infinite product over primes

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, numerical-methods, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

How can I compute
$$
\prod_p \left(1+\frac{k}{p}\right)\exp(-k/p)
$$
where $0<k<e$ and the product is over all primes $p$?

## Background

L. G. Sathe proved [1] that there are
$$
(1+o(1))f\left(\frac{\nu}{\log\log x}\right)\frac{x}{\log x}\frac{(\log\log x)^{\nu-1}}{(\nu-1)!}
$$
squarefree integers up to $x$ with $\nu$ prime factors, where $\nu$ grows as a fixed multiple of $\log\log x$ (constant from 0 to $e$). This is similar to Landau's earlier theorem which omits $f$ and fixes $\nu$. The definition of $f$ is
$$
f(k)=\frac{C^k}{\Gamma(k+1)}\prod_p\left(1+\frac kp\right)\exp(-k/p)
$$
with
$$
C=\prod_p\frac{p-1}{p}\exp(1/p)=0.7292647442571190188536\ldots
$$

Note that [MR0056625](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?r=1&pg1=CNO&s1=56625) misquotes the formula for $f$ above.

[1] L. G. Sathe, On a problem of Hardy on the distribution of integers having a given number of prime factors. I., J. Indian Math. Soc. (N.S.) 17 (1953), pp. 63-82.

Comment: To me, the product looks divergent. Should it perhaps be $$\prod_p \left(1+\frac{k}{p}\right)e^{-k/p}\,?$$

Comment: Wow, the constant is listed as [A240953](http://oeis.org/A240953).

Comment: As written, the product is divergent for $k \neq 0$. The value of the product is $0$ for $k < 0$, it is $1$ for $k = 0$, and $\infty$ for $k > 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I'll check at my uni library come Monday.

Comment: I tried to map it to an Euler product, but without success.

Comment: @DanielFischer: You're right. I was hasty in copying from MR (which is wrong!) rather than the original. I'll edit the question to fix this.

Comment: I guess you're satisfied with an approximation with good error bounds? If you take the logarithm, it reduces to finding $\sum_p \frac{1}{p^n}$ for $n \geqslant 2$, and cutting off where you think you are close enough. No idea what the best methods to compute the prime-zeta are, but for $n \geqslant 3$, brute force converges quickly enough to be an option.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I have a modestly efficient implementation of the prime zeta function but finding the right cutoffs and accounting for the omitted terms is not straightforward for me -- in particular, it's hard for me to guess how accurate my calculations are.

Comment: Do you mean the cutoffs and omitted terms in the computation of the prime zeta, or here in the product?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Here. The prime zeta function is already coded and working (with error < 1 ulp, I think).

Comment: Actually, you need to compute $\zeta_p(n) - 2^{-n}$. Since $2^{-n}$ is the dominating term of $\zeta_p(n)$, computing $\zeta_p$ within 1 ulp and then subtracting loses precision. Have you a method of computing $\zeta_p(n)-2^{-n}$ to the desired accuracy?

Comment: @DanielFischer: I don't, at the moment, but I could probably code it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the logarithm, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\log \prod_{p > k} \left(1 + \tfrac{k}{p}\right) \exp \left(- \tfrac{k}{p}\right)
&= \sum_{p > k} \log \left(1+\tfrac{k}{p}\right) - \tfrac{k}{p}\\
&= \sum_{p > k} \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{k^n}{n\cdot p^n}\\
&= \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{k^n}{n} \underbrace{\sum_{p > k} \frac{1}{p^n}}_{g_{k}(n)}.
\end{align}$$

The change of order of summation is legitimate by the absolute convergence.

Since $\frac{k^n}{n}g_k(n)$ is monotonically decreasing in $n$, we have an alternating series, and thus any two consecutive partial sums give bounds for the total sum, and the error is always smaller than the first omitted term.

For $k < 2$, we have $g_k(n) = \zeta_p(n)$, the prime zeta function, but we can also uniformly work with $g_2(n) = g_e(n) = \zeta_p(n) - 2^{-n}$ and multiply with $\left(1+\frac{k}{2}\right)\exp (-k/2)$ after exponentiating the computed approximation to the logarithm. It may however be more efficient to uniformly work with $g_m$ for larger $m$ and treat the primes $\leqslant m$ separately, since then the convergence of $\frac{k^n}{n}g_m(n)$ to $0$ is faster.

So altogether we have

$$\prod_p \left(1+\tfrac{k}{p}\right)\exp \left(-\tfrac{k}{p}\right) = \left[\prod_{p\leqslant m}\left(1+\tfrac{k}{p}\right)\exp \left(-\tfrac{k}{p}\right)\right] \exp \left(\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{k^n}{n}g_m(n) \right)$$

for arbitrary $m \geqslant k$. Choosing a larger $m$ leads to fewer $g_m(n)$ needed to achieve the desired accuracy, but computing

$$g_m(n) = \zeta_p(n) - \sum_{p \leqslant m} \frac{1}{p^n}$$

to the desired accuracy becomes more work the larger $m$ is. As a guesstimate, I'd think some $m \in [5,19]$ would give the best trade-off.